# SQL SUM(CASE) = 0

Tags: php, sql, case

I have a question. I have two Tables: customer and records. In the table customer, i have stored all my customers in the table records, all the mails i sent to the customers an all the phone calls i made. There are also some other types of records i save in that table for the customer

I now want to look for all the customers, that i sent no mails to and made no phone calls to.

I am using this SQL Query, which is not working:

```
 SELECT *, SUM(CASE WHEN Typ = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MailsSum, SUM(CASE WHEN Typ = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CallsSum FROM customer INNER JOIN records on records.KD_ID = customer.KD_ID GROUP BY KD_ID HAVING MailsSum = 0
```

Unfortunately this query is returning zero records.

Does anyone know how to do it right? :)

Cheers,
Niklas

Comment: You need to use LEFT JOIN to get the customers with no records.

Comment: select * group by one field is incorrect as well

Comment: Can you please explain Whats wrong about this Grouping? If i dont group, the query returns only one customer with the sums of all customers together. This Query with a LEFT JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN is working now - even for different VALUES in the HAVING Part for MailsSum and Calls Sum

@Barmar: Thanks!!!

Comment: A NULL value can also occur for example: 7 + NULL = NULL value.

Comment: @NiklasRiecken The problem isn't with grouping, it's with joining. `INNER JOIN` only returns rows that match between the two tables. If there's no matching row in `records`, then the corresponding `customer` will not be returned. `OUTER JOIN` returns a row for all rows in the first table, even if they don't match the second. See http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/